# TinyMCE windowManager - modal with scrollbars

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to create a modal window with `windowManager.open({...})` that will have a (probably long) list of items. Only way to ensure that it will display properly is to set fixed height to modal and make it's content scrollable.

[Documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3amethod.tinymce.WindowManager.open) on `windowManager.open` isn't really helping me here. I was able to find some examples describing `scrollbars` option:

```
editor.windowManager.open({        
    scrollbars: true,                    
    height: 300,
    ...            
});
```

But it is not working for me. If only someone could give me a hint on this, maybe I need to use some kind of [Panel](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aclass.tinymce.ui.Panel) for my modal's body?

I will really appreciate if someone could update my [Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ddeaab).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hah, I've spent all of yesterday trying to figure this out but as soon I've posted my question I've found the answer myself.

I was trying to repaint the dialog after setting `overflow: auto` manually by calling `win._bindings.repaint[0]()` and it gave me an error:

```
Cannot read property 'autoScroll' of undefined
```

And it turned out that `autoScroll` is what I was looking for:

```
editor.windowManager.open({        
    autoScroll: true,                    
    height: 300,
    ...            
});
```